# Speed up python code - can I vectorize double for loop?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I am new to python. I am using `dbscan` code for clustering purpose with some changes.Now code is running fine but its very slow. So I found out that I have to remove 'for loop' from my code.Here is a part of the code:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x = 0, y = 0, visited = False, isnoise = False):
        self.x = x  
        self.y = y  
        self.visited = False  
        self.isnoise = False  

    def show(self):  
        return self.x, self.y 

    def dist(self, p1, p2):  
        #Calculate the great circle distance between two points on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)return distance between two point  
        # convert decimal degrees to radians 
        dlat = radians(p2.x-p1.x)
        dlon = radians(p2.y-p1.y)
        a = sin(dlat/2) * sin(dlat/2) + cos(radians(p1.x))* cos(radians(p2.x)) * sin(dlon/2) * sin(dlon/2)
        c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a))
        d = 6371 * c
        return d 

    def distanceQuery(self,neighbor_pts):
        dista=[]
        for i in range(len(neighbor_pts)):
          for j in range(i+1,len(neighbor_pts)):
            z=self.dist(neighbor_pts[i],neighbor_pts[j])
            dista.append(z)
        return max(dista)
```

`distanceQuery` function is using double for loop. Is there any way I can remove this? Can I vectorize this double for loop? As this is clustering code there are some steps which require appending. I have read that numpy array work different than python list when it comes to appending. Appending numpy arrays is inefficient.

### Edit:

So this can be vectorize. But here is other part of code where appending is happening just after that I check for certain condition.

```
def expandCluster(self, P, neighbor_points):  
     self.cluster[self.cluster_inx].append(P)  
     iterator = iter(neighbor_points)  
     while True:  
       try:   
         npoint_tmp = iterator.next()  
       except StopIteration:  
         # StopIteration exception is raised after last element  
         break  
       if (not npoint_tmp.visited):  
         #for each point P' in NeighborPts   
         npoint_tmp.visited = True  
         NeighborPts_ = self.regionQuery(npoint_tmp)  
         if (len(NeighborPts_) >= self.MinPts):  
           for j in range(len(NeighborPts_)):  
            neighbor_points.append(NeighborPts_[j])
            if self.distanceQuery(neighbor_points)>0.10:
              break
```

Now if I vectorize neighbor_points also. I will have to tackle the problem of appending? So each point will append into `neighbour_points` and then it will make a `distanceQuery` . And this process is also part of a iteration. So kind of two loops are here also.I just want to make sure that appending in numpy array wont be inefficient

Comment: I think this might be an XY problem - can you describe what your goal is, rather, than just parts of the route that get you there? I think there might be a solution involving a [`scipy.spatial.KDTree`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html)

Comment: @Eric My goal is to get cluster using dbscan process but at the same time restrict those cluster with "max distance between any two points in that cluster". Somewhat I am trying to control size of the clusters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

def dist(p1, p2): 
    # Initially, p1.shape() == (n, 2) and p2.shape() == (m, 2)
    # Now, p1.shape() == (1, n, 2) and p2.shape() == (m, 1, 2)
    p1 = p1[np.newaxis, :, :]
    p2 = p2[:, np.newaxis, :]

    # get all the vectory things
    from numpy import sin, cos, radians, sqrt, arctan2 as atan2 

    # do the same math as before, but use `p[..., 0]` instead of `p.x` etc
    dlat = radians(p2[..., 0] - p1[..., 0])
    dlon = radians(p2[..., 1] - p1[..., 1])
    a = sin(dlat/2) * sin(dlat/2) + cos(p1[..., 0])*cos(p2[..., 0]) * sin(dlon/2) * sin(dlon/2)
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a))
    d = 6371 * c
    return d 

def distanceQuery(neighbor_pts):
    return np.max(dist(neighbor_pts, neighbor_pts))
```

e.g:

```
>>> points = np.array([[0, 0], [45, 0], [45, 45], [90, 0]], dtype=float) 
>>> dist(points, points)
array([[     0.        ,   5003.77169901,   6272.52596983,  10007.54339801],
       [  5003.77169901,      0.        ,   2579.12525679,   5003.77169901],
       [  6272.52596983,   2579.12525679,      0.        ,   4347.69702221],
       [ 10007.54339801,   5003.77169901,   4347.69702221,      0.        ]])
>>> np.max(_)
10007.543398010286
```

### Timing:

```
def dist_slow(p1, p2):
    """your function, adjusted to take an array instead of a `Point`"""
    from math import radians, cos, sqrt, atan2
    # compute the distance for all possible pairs
    dlat = radians(p2[0]-p1[0])
    dlon = radians(p2[1]-p1[1])

    a = sin(dlat/2) * sin(dlat/2) + cos(radians(p1[0]))*cos(radians(p2[0])) * sin(dlon/2) * sin(dlon/2)
    c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a))
    d = 6371 * c
    return d

def query_iter(p):
    return max(dist_slow(p1, p2) for p1, p2 in itertools.combinations(p, 2))

def query_orig(p):
    dista=[]
    for i in range(len(p)):
      for j in range(i + 1, len(p)):
        z = dist_slow(p[i], p[j])
        dista.append(z)
    return max(dista)

def query_mine(p):
    return dist(p, p).max()
```

Then:

```
>>> points = np.random.rand(1000, 2)
>>> timeit query_orig(points)
1 loops, best of 3: 7.94 s per loop
>>> timeit query_iter(points)
1 loops, best of 3: 7.35 s per loop
>>> timeit query_mine(points)
10 loops, best of 3: 150 ms per loop
```

Comment: Note, that you also need `import numpy as np` statement at the top (for `np.newaxis` at least)

Comment: this numpy solution should be much faster than the list comprehension suggested by others (anyone check if it is?)

Comment: So d is an array? I have to use dist in other steps also.

Comment: @usethedeathstar: Faster by a factor of about 50

Comment: @sau: `d[i, j]` is the distance between `p1[i]` and `p2[j]`.

Comment: @usethedeathstar: Although by doing even more work C-side in my other answer, it speeds up by a factor of 1000!

Comment: @Eric  If you dont do c= 2*something, and than d=6371*c, but just get max(something), you get another (marginal) speedup. On a sidenote: Personally i change lat,lon,alt coordinates to ECEF coordinates (x,y,z) and than take the sqrt((x0-x1)**2+(y0-y1)**2+(z0-z1)**2) to get the distances, since ECEF takes the flattening of the earth into account, as well as the altitudes of both points.

Answer (score 4):

You can do everything in "vector" form with numpy ufunc:

```
from numpy import radians, sin, cos, sqrt, arctan2
from numpy import random

def max_dist(p1x,p1y,p2x,p2y):
    # give them "orthogonal" shape
    p1x = p1x.reshape(p1x.size,1)
    p1y = p1y.reshape(p1y.size,1)
    p2x = p2x.reshape(1,p2x.size)
    p2y = p2y.reshape(1,p2y.size)

    # compute the distance for all possible pairs
    dlat = radians(p2x-p1x)
    dlon = radians(p2y-p1y)

    a = sin(dlat/2) * sin(dlat/2) + cos(radians(p1x))*cos(radians(p2x)) * sin(dlon/2) * sin(dlon/2)
    c = 2 * arctan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a))
    d = 6371 * c

    return d.max()


if __name__=='__main__':
    # generate random samples
    N = 1000
    p1x,p1y,p2x,p2y = random.rand(4,N)

    print 'max_dist=',max_dist(p1x,p1y,p2x,p2y)
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about vectorizing, but you can certainly turn the double-for loop into a list comprehension. And since you just take the max value of that list, you can just as well use a generator expression for that.

```
def distGen(pts):
    return max(dist(pts[i], pts[j]) for i in range(len(pts)) 
                                    for j in range(i+1, len(pts)))
```

I did some timing analysis on this and this seems to be at least a bit faster. Interestingly, though, contrary to my intuition, using a list comprehension instead of a generator is even faster, but the generator should have the advantage of using far less memory.

```
1.15502595901   # your approach
1.37675499916   # your approach single max value var instead of list
1.00971293449   # above generator expression
0.916918992996  # above with list comprehension, i.e., max([...])
```

(Tested with Python 2.7 using a list of 1000 random numbers instead of Points and `dist` measuring the absolute distance between those numbers.)

---

Even better -- much cleaner and still a bit faster -- is using `itertools.combinations` to get all the combinations of two points:

```
import itertools
def distComb(pts):
    return max(dist(p1, p2) for p1, p2 in itertools.combinations(pts, 2))
```

Comment: You still have double loop, both in generator expression and in `combinations()` function, though now expressed implicitly. Execution time is reduced due to putting part of execution into C level, but essentially algorithms stays the same.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution, which first maps all your points onto a unit sphere:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial

def sphereify(points):
    """lat, long -> x, y, z  for a unit sphere"""
    lat = np.radians(points[:, 0, np.newaxis])
    long = np.radians(points[:, 1, np.newaxis])
    return np.hstack((
        np.cos(lat) * np.cos(long),
        np.cos(lat) * np.sin(long),
        np.sin(lat)
    ))


def arcDistance(chordDistance):
    """Get the surface distance corresponding to the chord distance""" 
    return np.arcsin(chordDistance / 2) * 2

earthRadius = 6371
def query(points):
    dists = scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(sphereify(points))
    surfaceDist = earthRadius * arcDistance(dist.max())
    return surfaceDist
```

Then:

```
>>>  timeit query(points)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.23 ms per loop
```